# Assign a delegate to instance of a class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Hi guys hope you are doing good. I have a doubt in when I try to use custom delegate function the call back function is not being called without using prepare segue or present view controller is it possible to achecive this without these two concepts are used to only for handle front and back controllers directly . Simply I say I have 3 viewControllers and I want to update my firstviewcontroller label when I did something in 3rd view controller. Is it possible via delegate? Please help me out I am struggling for last two days I could not find an answer so please guide me.

Here is my code
In my 3rd view controller

```
protocol ThirdViewControllerDelegate: class {    
    func updateLabel(title: String)
}
```

Then I have created a property `weak var delegate: ThirdViewControllerDelegate?`

And I have assigned a value in

```
@IBAction func thirdControllerButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {        
    delegate?.updateLabel(title: "iOS_Developer")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And I have adopted this delegate in my first view controller and

```
lazy var thirdController = ThirdViewController()
thirdController.delegate = self

func updateLabel(title: String) {
    print("Your updated Label is \(title)")
}
```

But this function not being called . Here how can I set delegate reference so please help me.

Comment: Where in your first view controller do you set the delegate? And how do you navigate to `thirdController`?

Comment: You're creating a new ThirdViewController() in your var declaration, not the one that is being accessed, presumably by the storyboard. In your prepareForSegue: function, get the destination view controller then set the delegate.

Comment: i am presenting the controller using @DávidPásztor
 self.present(FirstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: i do not want to use prepare segue or present view controller. is it possible to achieve using via instance of a class where i have created delegate @JonJ

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code for the view controllers which show setting the delegate, using it and the push and pop operations?

Comment: @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.updateLabel(label: "iOS Developer")
        let firstvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
        self.present(firstvc, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
I am dismissing my thirdController like this only

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
      sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

or:

```
let vc = ThirdViewController()
vc.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller

Here's a diagram which hopefully shows how the view controllers communicate with each other via delegates:

[image]

Comment: can you share this as example. i can not understand here in third view controller i am presenting to first controller after launching first controller will show a value but here how can i make reference like vc.delegate = self  because i have it in thirdviewcontroller

Comment: I've added a diagram showing delegate communication.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JonJ . i can understand we may assign delegate via Push or present viewController using navigation  but here i want is to access the data from third view controller to first view controller. So how can i set delegate for first controller in last view controller i am presenting view controller using present method so please help me i am new one for ios developement.